# Special character data migration

Tags: mysql, csv, character-encoding, special-characters

I have to migrate a database from *Oracle* to *MySql* having billions of data. I found a strategy to create a schema and get the data in *CSV from Oracle* and load data to MySQL. I have created a CSV file with a delimiter of a quote(") and field terminated with a comma(,). Now the problem is that CSV file *contains* **special character** which is not going to be imported in MySql.

I am using the **command:**

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL infile 'C:/Users/NNCP4659/export.csv' INTO TABLE dbk_address_master 
CHARACTER SET utf8 fields terminated BY "," enclosed by '"' lines terminated 
BY "\r\n"(id, country_code,address,city_id,latitude,longitude, 
@is_active,google_address,old_address,building_number,street_name,created_by) 
set is_active=cast(@is_active as signed);
```

My data is like:

```
4113973,"CHE","167 Bernerstrasse Süd","57066","47.3943271","8.4865849",1,"Bernerstrasse Süd 167, 8048 Zürich, 
Switzerland","167 Bernerstrasse Süd","Y","167","Bernerstrasse Süd","migration"
```

And error is:

> ERROR 1300 (HY000): Invalid utf8 character string: '"167 
>       Bernerstrasse S'

Comment: Sounds like the `ü` is not encoded as `utf8`.  Can you get a hex dump of that line?  Also, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE dbk_address_master;`

Comment: Issue is in address column which is as: `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the export code or method.

Answer (score 1):

`167 Bernerstrasse S` looks like the truncation of `167 Bernerstrasse Süd` at the first non-utf8 character.

You have specified that the incoming data is utf8 via

```
 LOAD DATA ... CHARACTER SET utf8 ...
```

I conclude that the incoming file is not encoded correctly.  It is probably latin1, in which case the hex would be `FC`.  Assuming this is the case, you should switch to

```
 LOAD DATA ... CHARACTER SET latin1 ...
```

It does not matter if the `CHARACTER SET` in the target column is not latin1; MySQL will transcode it in flight.

(Alternatively, you could change the incoming data to have utf8 (hex: `C3BC`), but that may be more hassle.)

Reference:  "truncated" in [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

(As for how to check the hex, or do `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, we need to know what OS you are using and what tools you have available.)

Comment: It's fixed now. I have used CHARACTER SET latin1.